# Issue with SparkR regexp_extract function

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

**Data**

I work with a large dataset (280 million rows) for which Spark and R seems to work nicely.

**Problem**

I'd had problems with SparkR's `regexp_extract` function. I thought it to work analogically to Stringr's `str_detect` but I haven't managed to get it to work. The documentation for `regexp_extract` is limited. Could you please give me a hand?

**Reprex**

Here is a reprex where I try to identify strings that do not have a space and paste " 00:01" as a suffix.

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(sparklyr)
library(SparkR)

# Create data
df <- data.frame(sampletaken = c("06/03/2013", "29/11/2005 8:30", "06/03/2013", "15/01/2007 12:25", "06/03/2013", "15/01/2007 12:25"))

# Create Spark connection
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", spark_home = spark_home_dir())

# Transfer data to Spark memory
df <- copy_to(sc, df, "df", overwrite = TRUE)

# Modify data
df1 <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(sampletaken = ifelse(regexp_extract(sampletaken, " "), sampletaken, paste(sampletaken, "00:01")))

# Collect data as dataframe
df1 <- df1 %>% as.data.frame()
head(df1$sampletaken)
```

**Error**

error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(NOT regexp_extract(df.`sampletaken`, ' ', 1))' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires boolean type, however, 'regexp_extract(df.`sampletaken`, ' ', 1)' is of string type.; line 1 pos 80;

**Solution**

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(sparklyr)
library(SparkR)

# Create data
df <- data.frame(sampletaken = c("06/03/2013", "29/11/2005 8:30", "06/03/2013", "15/01/2007 12:25", "06/03/2013", "15/01/2007 12:25"))

# Create Spark connection
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", spark_home = spark_home_dir())

# Transfer data to Spark memory
df <- copy_to(sc, df, "df", overwrite = TRUE)

# Modify data
df1 <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(sampletaken1 = ifelse(rlike(sampletaken, " "), sampletaken, paste(sampletaken, "00:01")))

# Collect data as dataframe
df1 <- df1 %>% as.data.frame()
head(df1$sampletaken)
```

Comment: `regexp_extract` seems to extract a pattern from string, it doesn't "detect" it as `str_detect` and I couldn't find `regexp_detect`.  Does simple base R  `grepl` doesn't work in spark? Something like `df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(sampletaken = ifelse(grepl(" ", sampletaken), sampletaken, paste(sampletaken, "00:01")))`

Comment: Thank you @RonakShah for contributing. `grep` does not solve the issue, but you are indeed correct that the function extracts and not identifies the string.

This does not help either

```# Modify data
df1 <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(sampletaken1 = regexp_extract(sampletaken, " "))```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `rlike` is what you're after if you're looking for the analog to `str_detect`, see the [SQL API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#rlike):

> `str rlike regexp` - Returns `true` if `str` matches `regexp`, or `false` otherwise.

```
SELECT '%SystemDrive%\Users\John' rlike '%SystemDrive%\\Users.*'
true
```

on a `Column` (i.e., in R, rather than in SparkQL through `sql()`), it would be like:

```
rlike(Column, 'regex.*pattern')

# i.e., in magrittr form
Column %>% rlike('regex.*pattern')
```

Note that [`like`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#like) is usually more efficient if you can use it since the set of valid `like` patterns is much smaller.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MichaelChirico! This was really helpful! The solution was

```# Modify data
df1 <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(sampletaken1 = ifelse(rlike(sampletaken, " "), sampletaken, paste(sampletaken, "00:01")))```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SparkR, but it seems that the function regex_extract returns a string (presumably the matched pattern in the string) instead of a boolean, as required by the function ifelse.

You may try to match the returned value against the empty string.

Comment: Thanks @Giovanni Zecca for your contribution. You are correct that this extracts instead of detecting the string. I think your suggestion should be correct, but was not able to make it work.

```# Modify data
df1 <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(sampletaken1 = ifelse(regexp_extract(sampletaken, " ") == " ", sampletaken, paste(sampletaken, "00:01")));
df1 <- df1 %>% as.data.frame();
head(df1$sampletaken1)```